# C++ array input/output

Tags: c++, arrays

I can't seem to figure out why my program is only displaying the last 300 elements in the array, or if the array has only 300 elements in it when the loop is set to 500. The text file defiantly has 500 lines with 3 sets of numbers on each line. Thanks :).

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct colour
{
    int r, g, b;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ifstream inf;

    inf.open("rgb.txt");
    colour array[500];

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        inf >> array[i].r >> array[i].g >> array[i].b;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i].r << array[i].g << array[i].b << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Update solution: https://superuser.com/questions/99066/how-to-keep-all-of-the-output-of-a-program-on-the-windows-command-line

Changing the buffer height of CMD above 500 allowed me to display all 500 elements in the console.

Comment: Sounds like it might be too long for console output, have you tried piping to a file?

Comment: print the counter as well

Comment: Post the file, also you need to check the stream on each loop in case reading fails.

Comment: Hi guys, when I output this to a text file, all 500 lines are written, so the problem is the console then hmmm.

Comment: I just tried printing out 500 lines in a console window and it worked without any problems. Which console are you using?

Comment: I have found a solution, thanks for all your suggestions, I will edit the question with the solution just in case  others have this problem.

Comment: On Windows, right click the title bar and go to properties. Change screen buffer height to be more than 300 lines.

Comment: @prettycooldevguy thank you, that was the problem I had :)